# How can i get items of SupervisoryReview folder from exchange online using ews-managed-api?

Tags: c#, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to develope my C# desktop application using EWS with Exchange Oneline on Office 365 Enterprise E5 subscription. I set up the Supervision policy on Security & Compliance menu to inspect 
all of mail messages on my organizations. I can see the messages on SupervisoryReview folder in my Office 365 web mail and Outlook 2016 after i set up the mailbox profile ("SupervisoryReview{GUID}@company.onmicrosoft.com") I'd like to access that SupervisoryReview folder using EWS to store mails to auditing agency's database. but i don't know hot to do this i can't find folder id using EWS. Please Help me?

Comment: Can you see the folder in the ewsditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ this is just a simple EWS client. If you can see the folder there and access the content just a normal findfolder will do it.